# i found error in loading a simple .js file at document .write?

Tags: document.write

i had written a code and found an error at document .write what to do ?

code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").document.write=('hi');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Head</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'write' of undefined
    at myFunction (test1.html:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test1.html:16)
myFunction @ test1.html:6
onclick @ test1.html:16
```

help me out!

Comment: I'd guess you should remove the `=` after `write`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is : you use some things that doesn't exists

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and there is no property `document` on [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) (and even if there was it would make you go back to the original document).

So:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").document === undefined
```

that's what your error is saying.

---

but removing it will not be enought as there is no `Element.write()`

The solution is to use either [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`Element.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) which are used as normal strings.
The difference between the two is that `innerHTML` allow you to write HTML tags which will be rendered, while `textContent` escape HTML tag in order to print the string as is it in your sources.

Exemple of `innerHTML` and `textContent` :

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demoTextContent").textContent = 'hi';
  document.getElementById("demoInnerHTML").innerHTML = 'hi';
}

function myFunction2() {
  content = document.getElementById("demoTextContent").textContent
  document.getElementById("demoTextContent").textContent = content + 'hi';
  // these to line can also be written as
  // document.getElementById("demoTextContent").textContent += 'hi';
  
  content = document.getElementById("demoInnerHTML").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("demoInnerHTML").innerHTML = content + 'hi';
  // these to line can also be written as
  // document.getElementById("demoInnerHTML").innerHTML += 'hi';
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("demoTextContent").textContent = '<span style="background-color:cyan;">hi</span>';
  document.getElementById("demoInnerHTML").innerHTML = '<span style="background-color:cyan;">hi</span>';
}
```

```css
#demoTextContent::before {content: "textContent: ";}
#demoInnerHTML::before{content:"innerHTML: ";}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript in Head</h2>

<p id="demoTextContent"></p>
<p id="demoInnerHTML"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()">Try replace text</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Try append</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction3()">Try replace by html code</button>
```

---

also you wrote

```
write=('hi')
```

the `=` may be a typo but `JavaScript` will read it as `write = ('hi')` later traslated to `write = 'hi'`.

Already had something like this, spent almost an hour finding it :p.